# About BOOTCMD in Uboot

Tags: linux, arm, u-boot

My board is S3C6410, When i read the source code of uboot. there is something troubles me.

`#define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND    "nand read 0xc0008000 0x100000 0x500000;bootm 0xc0008000"`

what does it mean ?    it read the data from address of nand: 0x100000 , size of: 0x500000. To 0xc0008000 (SD-RAM), is it ?..
But the start-address of SD-RAM is : 0x50000000, how does address of 0xc0008000 make sense ?...out of range ?
Thanks.

my sdram size: 256M... nand boot..

There is some configure about it.

```
#define MEMORY_BASE_ADDRESS 0x50000000
#define CONFIG_NR_DRAM_BANKS    1      /* we have 2 bank of DRAM */
#define PHYS_SDRAM_1        MEMORY_BASE_ADDRESS /* SDRAM Bank #1 */
//#define PHYS_SDRAM_1_SIZE 0x08000000 /* 64 MB */
#define PHYS_SDRAM_1_SIZE   0x10000000

#define CFG_FLASH_BASE      0x00000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are reading it right. Address of 0xc0008000 would be destination of the read from nand.

I'd suggest you stop board boot to get U-Boot command prompt. Then do printenv, that may show something in your target setup that overrides the source you have shown. Also try the command manually.

Answer (score 0):

it means 0x100000 address and 0x500000 size of nand  should be written at address 0xc0008000.